# Games and the right mathematical framework for GANs

Tags: computational-complexity, computer-science, game-theory, machine-learning, learning-theory

Generative Adversarial Networks were introduced in http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5423-generative-adversarial-nets and has more than [20000 citations](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=11977070277539609369&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en).

It is an important topic within deep learning.

1. Are the modeling of training as two player games an imperfect information game? If so how to interpret it as such?
2. From complexity theory perspective two player games can be $\mathsf{PSPACE}$-complete. In GANs we attempt to solve a transportation problem in the framework of two player games by being within stochastic gradient descent. The transportation problem seems to be a problem in $\mathsf{PH}$. Is it overdone to be looking at it as a two-player game and are we doing it the right way by using $\mathsf{SGD}$?

Comment: It's probably not fair to attribute GAN soley to Goodfellow, as Schmidhuber deserves at least a moiety of the credit.

Comment: Yeah there is always a struggle on what is a new idea. From computer science point of view most ideas are mundane and we choose who gets the milk from the cow and at this time the milk recipient has already been chosen by the community. This question is not about ideas or milk recipients and takes the reality of things as they are as of how they are studied now.

Comment: The point I am trying to make here is either two player games are a overkill or sgd is not sufficient. The question is involved and is not direct to answer and you need expertise in transportation theory, game theory and computational complexity theory.

Comment: There are some papers that explicitly connect GANs with game theory, e.g., the [2017 paper on GANGs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.00679.pdf). From a computational complexity point of view, [the complexity of computing a Nash equilibrium](http://people.csail.mit.edu/costis/simplified.pdf) is PPAD-complete.

Comment: However two player games are pspace complete. How do we know an equilibrium exists in the case of GANS? It still appears using randomness and jumping around using sgd gets the equilibria should be a silly attempt if ppad completeness is the correct complexity (seems bpp can provide approximate solutions to ppad problems which would be unlikely).

Comment: First of all, I don't know exactly what you mean by "two player games are PSPACE complete." For example, [generalized chess is EXPTIME-complete](https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(81)90016-9). So it's at most a rule of thumb and not a theorem. Second, if you really want to make contact with complexity theory, then it's up to you to devise a sufficiently precise notion of a GAN that theorems can be proved about it. The notion of a GAN, as practitioners understand that term, is a bit fuzzy. To prove something rigorous, you need a more precise definition of GAN than is commonly used.

Comment: Third, even if you come up with a precise definition and prove PPAD-completeness, that is probably going to say almost nothing at all about what kinds of techniques are going to work in practice. It is a very general fact that the practical performance of heuristic algorithms is something that we often cannot explain theoretically. This is true for many classic hard problems, and it applies in spades to neural nets.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I am only trying to make the following point. Either we are not utilizing the full power of such games or indeed if we are then sgd cannot be the right strategy and if indeed is correct strategy then probably we can model with a simpler apparatus gaining insight to approaching the neural network model soundly.

Answer (score 1):

That GANs are both inspired and conceptually linked with Mathematical Game Theory is undeniable.

From the initial **Goodfellow' s model** quite a lot of water has been running under the mill. Many different variants of GAN has been proposed (and implemented), some of those less obviously coupled to the standard paradigm of zero sum two-players game.*

However, what is remarkable is that the liaison between GANS and Game Theory persists, *mutatis mutandis* (for instance you can have 3 players rather than one, or some kinds of cooperation, etc).

[Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.06976.pdf) is a great summary on recent work on **GANs and Games**.

Anyway, assuming even the original GAN architecture, the issue of Nash Equilibria is far from trivial. Apparently, there are GANs where there is no corresponding Nash equilibrium, see [here](https://mitibmwatsonailab.mit.edu/research/blog/do-gans-always-have-nash-equilibria/) .

Lastly, complexity. In the light of the above, it is clear that speaking of complexity classes associated to GANs beg the question:

which GAN we pick?

and, equally important:

which game are we playing?